# Transparent Navigation Bar Android 13 (Tiramisu)

Tags: android, navigationbar

Previous approaches to create a transparent navigation bar on Android do not work with SDK 33 (Android 13 - Tiramisu) anymore. At least on tablets where the navigation bar now contains some app shortcuts and a button to open the launcher app menu. Does anyone have a solution, yet?

Tried approaches:

```java
Window w = getWindow();
w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
w.setNavigationBarColor(oT.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {                
    w.setNavigationBarContrastEnforced(false);
}
```

Adding

```java
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

or xml/style attributes has no effect either. The flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` hides the navigation bar, but I would like to still have it visible and usable, just with a transparent background.